# Why doesn't my TStringList gets sorted

Tags: delphi, sorting, tstringlist

I Have a TStringList  I create on FormCreate

```
  ScriptList := TStringList.Create;
```

In another function in my program after I have loaded strings into the list I have the following code

```
  ScriptList.Sorted := True;
  ScriptList.Sort;
  for i := 0 to ScriptList.Count - 1 do
    ShowMessage(ScriptList[i]);
```

But the list is not sorted
Why is that?

Edited:
Filling the list is done by the following code

```
function TfrmMain.ScriptsLocate(const aComputer: boolean = False): integer;
var
  ScriptPath: string;
  TempList: TStringList;
begin
  TempList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if aComputer = True then
      begin
        ScriptPath := Folders.DirScripts;
        Files.Search(TempList, ScriptPath, '*.logon', False);
        ScriptList.AddStrings(TempList);
      end
    else
      begin
        if ServerCheck then
          begin
            ScriptPath := ServerPath + 'scripts_' + Network.ComputerName + '\';
            Folders.Validate(ScriptPath);
            TempList.Clear;
            Files.Search(TempList, ScriptPath, '*.logon', False);
            ScriptList.AddStrings(TempList);
            Application.ProcessMessages;

            ScriptPath := ServerPath + 'scripts_' + 'SHARED\';
            Folders.Validate(ScriptPath);
            TempList.Clear;
            Files.Search(TempList, ScriptPath, '*.logon', False);
            ScriptList.AddStrings(TempList);
          end;
      end;
  finally
    TempList.Free;
  end;
  ScriptList.Sort;
  Result := ScriptList.Count;
end;
```

The filesearch function:

```
function TFiles.Search(aList: TstringList; aPathname: string; const aFile: string = '*.*'; const aSubdirs: boolean = True): integer;
var
  Rec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Folders.Validate(aPathName, False);
  if FindFirst(aPathname + aFile, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        aList.Add(aPathname + Rec.Name);
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;
  Result := aList.Count;
  if not aSubdirs then Exit;
  if FindFirst(aPathname + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..') then
          Files.Search(aList, aPathname + Rec.Name, aFile, True);
        until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;
  Result := aList.Count;
end;
```

The main problem is that the list is filled OK with the items I want, but it never gets sorted.

Answer (score 8):

When you set `Sorted` to `True` you are saying that you want the list to be maintained in order. When new items are added, they will be inserted in order. When `Sorted` is `True`, the `Sort` method does nothing because the code is built on the assumption that the list is already order.

So, in your code calling `Sort` does nothing and could be removed. However, I would take the alternative approach, remove the setting of `Sorted` and call `Sort` explicitly:

```
ScriptList.LoadFromFile(...);
ScriptList.Sort;
for i := 0 to ScriptList.Count - 1 do
  ...
```

---

Now, in fact I think that your code is not quite as you have claimed. You claim that you load the file, and then set `Sorted` to `True`. That cannot be the case. Here is the `SetSorted` implementation:

```
procedure TStringList.SetSorted(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FSorted <> Value then
  begin
    if Value then Sort;
    FSorted := Value;
  end;
end;
```

So, if `Sorted` is `False` when you set it to `True`, the list will be sorted.

---

But even that does not explain what you report. Because if `Sorted` is `True` when you call `LoadFromFile`, each new line will be inserted in order. So, what you report in the question cannot be the whole story.

---

Unless you are making subsequent additions to the list, it is cleaner, in my view, to ignore the `Sorted` property. Leave `Sorted` as its default value of `False`. And call `Sort` when you want to enforce an ordering to the list. All the same, it might be worth digging a bit deeper to understand why your assertions in the question don't tally with the implementation of `TStringList`.

Comment: I can see that my question could lead to the assumption that I load the items from a file - this is not the case. What I do is to search 2 directories for files of a certain type and add them to the list. After that I want the list to sort.

Comment: All the same, the code in the question will result in the list being sorted. So I think you should make a short SSCCE to show what you mean.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what SSCCE is :-)     I have edited the question to include some more code.

Comment: You can use Google to find what SSCCE is